# react-native-popup-menu slide to the top

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I already read the documentation but it seem there is no way to made the animation to slide to up
or just made it to show from bottom to the top.

```
<MenuProvider>
    <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"}}>
    <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    <Menu >
        <MenuTrigger text='Select action'/>
        <MenuOptions style={{top:0,right:0}}>
            <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Save`)} text='Save' />
            <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Delete`)} >
            <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>Delete</Text>
            </MenuOption>
            <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Not called`)} disabled={true} text='Disabled' />
        </MenuOptions>
    </Menu>
    </View>
</MenuProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use renderer={renderers.SlideInMenu}

At the top

```
 import {MenuProvider,
            Menu,
            MenuOptions,
            MenuOption,
            MenuTrigger,
            renderers} from 'react-native-popup-menu';
```

then just renders in menu component

```
    <MenuProvider>
    <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"}}>
    <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    <Menu render={renderers.SlideMenu} >
        <MenuTrigger text='Select action'/>
        <MenuOptions style={{top:0,right:0}}>
            <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Save`)} text='Save' />
            <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Delete`)} >
            <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>Delete</Text>
            </MenuOption>
            <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Not called`)} disabled={true} text='Disabled' />
        </MenuOptions>
    </Menu>
    </View>
</MenuProvider>
```

then you try styling the MenuOptions to change the style on popup
more documentation here:
renderer:https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/9808ebfe5a7914fa9bad36c72174c4dd5f52366a/doc/extensions.md

style:https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/HEAD/doc/api.md